# MSSQL - Adding condition on the where and on clause performance

Tags: sql-server, query-optimization, database-performance

Consider the following two queries:

```
select *
from 
   table1 t1
      left join
   table2 t2
      on t1.Id = t2.t1Id and (t1.Status = 1 or t2.Id is not null)
```

And this one

```
select *
from 
   table1 t1
      left join
   table2 t2
      on t1.Id = t2.t1Id 
where
   t1.Status = 1 or t2.Id is not null
```

The first one runs in 2 seconds. The second one in 2 minutes. Shouldn't the execution plan be the same?

Comment: They produce different result sets. Logically, they couldn't have exactly the same plan.

Comment: Please elaborate on this. What's the difference in result.

Comment: Using `declare @table1 table (Id int, Status int)
declare @table2 table (Id int, T1Id int)

insert into @table1 (ID,Status) values
(1,1),
(2,2)
insert into @table2 (Id, T1Id) values
(1,1)` as your tables 1 and 2, the first query produces 2 rows. The second produces 1.

Comment: @AthanasiosKataras - it's because you're using a LEFT JOIN. The first query will return rows with NULL values where not in table 2. The second query will not return those rows.
If it was an INNER JOIN, they would essentially be the same query.

Comment: I understand that the way I'm writing the query will first bring the null values, but they will eventually be filtered out by the where clause, effectively returnig the same result. I would expect the query plan to figure this out and produce the same plan.

Comment: Thanks Damien, I visuallized it and got the result! Cheers!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The query plans are different because the queries (and results) are different.

You're using a LEFT JOIN, so the first query will return rows with NULL values where not in table 2.
The second query will not return those rows.

If it was an INNER JOIN, they would essentially be the same query.

Comment: I argue that it does not produce different results. Wether the filter is applied during the joining of the tables or after they are joined, the result should be the same.

Comment: Read my post again - it explains why it can produce different results, and Damien The Unbeliever gave you example data where this is the case in a comment on the original post.

Comment: Ok, got it. I visuallized. it. The is not null in the first case, does not apply to the result set but at the value itself.

Comment: The first query filters what data is returned FROM TABLE2, the second query filters what appears in your results. A left join will return records showing NULL for records in table1 but not table2. An INNER JOIN (or a WHERE filter) will not return records that don't meet that criteria in the results.

Comment: @AthanasiosKataras - sorry posted at same time... yes that's right.

Answer (score 1):

Here the Below Query Returns all the "Table1" results with additional matching Columns based on the "ON Clause" condition.

```
select * from table1 t1
left join table2 t2
on t1.Id = t2.t1Id and (t1.Status = 1 or t2.Id is not null)
```

Now, the below query matches the 2 tables and returns the rows based on the ON Clause and an additional **WHERE** Clause filters the Rows again based on the Condition.

```
select * from 
table1 t1
left join table2 t2 on t1.Id = t2.t1Id 
where t1.Status = 1 or t2.Id is not null
```

Here, Even though we used **LEFT JOIN** But in this case it acts like an **INNER JOIN**

So, Here Both the Queries produce Different Result Sets. The Execution Plan Also Vary which results in Different Execution Time.

Comment: I argue that it does not produce different results. Wether the filter is applied during the joining of the tables or after they are joined, the result should be the same.

Answer (score 0):

The best way to deal with an `OR` is to eliminate it (if possible) or break it into smaller queries. Breaking a short and simple query into a longer, more drawn-out query may not seem elegant, but when dealing with `OR` problems, it is often the best choice:

```
select *
from table1 t1
     left join table2 t2 t1.Id = t2.t1Id 
where t1.Status = 1
union all
select *
from table1 t1
     left join table2 t2 t1.Id = t2.t1Id 
where t2.Id is not null
```

You can read more in this article:
https://www.sqlshack.com/query-optimization-techniques-in-sql-server-tips-and-tricks/